# Error when creating Database Tables - CKAN

Tags: python, centos, virtualenv, ckan, paster

i'm trying to install CKAN 2.5.2 on Centos 6.8

When i run paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini

i get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==2.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 205, in command
    self._load_config(cmd!='upgrade')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 142, in _load_config
    conf = self._get_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 139, in _get_config
    return appconfig('config:' + self.filename)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 261, in appconfig
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
    section)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 646, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ckan.config.environment import load_environment
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 18, in <module>
    import ckan.lib.helpers as h
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/helpers.py", line 30, in <module>
    from bleach import clean as clean_html
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bleach/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from html5lib.sanitizer import HTMLSanitizer
ImportError: No module named sanitizer
```

I was following [wiki instructions](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.5.2-on-CentOS-6.8)

I'm stuck on this step and don't know how to proceed.

Module html5lib is imported and updated to latest version. Paster script is executed in virtualenv under root account.

Also i'm running all of this in python2.6 since that is default on Centos.

Some additional information

when i run python and import html5lib and then help(html5lib) i get this

```
>>> import html5lib
>>> help(html5lib)
Help on package html5lib:

NAME
    html5lib

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/html5lib/__init__.py

DESCRIPTION
    HTML parsing library based on the WHATWG "HTML5"
    specification. The parser is designed to be compatible with existing
    HTML found in the wild and implements well-defined error recovery that
    is largely compatible with modern desktop web browsers.

    Example usage:

    import html5lib
    f = open("my_document.html")
    tree = html5lib.parse(f)

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    _ihatexml
    _inputstream
    _tokenizer
    _trie (package)
    _utils
    constants
    filters (package)
    html5parser
    serializer
    treeadapters (package)
    treebuilders (package)
    treewalkers (package)

CLASSES
    __builtin__.object
        html5lib.html5parser.HTMLParser

    class HTMLParser(__builtin__.object)
     |  HTML parser. Generates a tree structure from a stream of (possibly
     |  malformed) HTML
     |
     |  Methods defined here:
:
```

There is no sanitizer here. Do i need to use specific version of html5lib?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please include the full stack trace, not this partial one.

Comment: Full stack trace added.

Comment: Great, but now you missed the error line at the bottom of the stacktrace!

Comment: I got the same on Centos 7, the problem appears to be related to a recent change on html5lib, take a look on 
https://github.com/mozilla/bleach/issues/212#issuecomment-233232734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 copies of html5lib installed. When you did help(html5lib) it is showing a copy that is installed in your user's python directory (/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/) not the virtualenv that you have ckan (and bleach) installed (/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.6/site-packages/). So get rid of the former to avoid confusion.

Yes I think you have the wrong version of html5lib, since sanitizer is listed in the package contents when I do help.

This is the correct version (at the time of writing - in future check what is in requirements.txt):

```
$ pip freeze | grep html5lib
html5lib==0.9999999
```

Comment: Thank you. all those nines are confusing. I will pay more attention to requirements.txt. Everything is ok now, except i have internal server error on http//mydomain.com/dataset. But that is something completely different.

Comment: I think its incorrect, the problem is because a recent change on package: 
https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/277

Comment: Yes, the problem is with a change seen in html5lib 0.999999999. The fix is still to revert to html5lib 0.9999999. This will be fixed in forthcoming releases - see https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3257#issuecomment-249828493 / https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3214